# Datagridview comboboxcolumn different values for each row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcomboboxcell

I want to create a datagridview with comboboxcolumns using c#.

The problem is that I dont know how to give different values for combobox in each row.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("state");
dt.Columns.Add("city");
dt.Rows.Add("a1", "b1");
dt.Rows.Add("a1", "b2");
dt.Rows.Add("a2", "b3");
dt.Rows.Add("a2", "b4");
dt.Rows.Add("a3", "b5");
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboStates = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
comboStates.HeaderText = "HeaderText_1";
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(0, comboStates);
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn comboCities = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
comboCities.HeaderText = "HeaderText_2";
this.dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(1, comboCities);

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    comboStates.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][0]);
        DataGridViewComboBoxCell stateCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)    (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0]);
    stateCell.Value = comboStates.Items[i];
    comboCities.Items.Add(dt.Rows[i][1]);
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cityCell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1]);
    cityCell.Value = comboCities.Items[i];
}
```

This example gives the following results :

for each row:

comboboxcolumnstate :

```
a1
a1
a2
a2
a3
```

comboboxcolumncity :

```
b1
b2
b3
b4
b5
```

I know this is normal because I am looping through datatable.

So how can i get this result:

row1: comboboxcolumnstate comboboxcolumncity

```
             a1               b1 - b2
```

row2: comboboxcolumnstate comboboxcolumncity

```
             a2               b3 - b4
```

row2: comboboxcolumnstate comboboxcolumncity

```
             a3               b5
```

I am new to C#. I searched a lot but I didn't find a solution which solve this issue.
Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is an example code that should get you started.

First I create a list of values (cities) for each state. For this the  `Dictionary` collection comes handy:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string state = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    string city  = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();

    if (! dict.Keys.Contains(state ))  dict.Add(state, new List<string>());
    dict[state].Add(city);
}
```

I loop over your table and for each row I add a new entry for the city and, if necessary, for the state.

Now we modify the setup of the DGV to use those `Lists` in the `Items` of each of the `DataGridViewComboBoxCell`.

Note: Here the key is to use the `DataGridViewComboBoxCells`, and **not** the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumns`!

For easier access I create string variables for the state and city values again..

```
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string state = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
    string city = dt.Rows[i][1].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell stateCell = 
                            (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0]);
    stateCell.Items.AddRange(dict.Keys.ToArray());
    stateCell.Value = state;
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cityCell = 
                            (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1]);
    cityCell.Items.AddRange(dict[state].ToArray());
    cityCell.Value = city;
}
```

Note: This sets up the values in the DropDowns, but after each change in a 'State' column you will need to adapt the 'Cities' column in that row! Therefore it would be a good idea to make the `Dictionary` **persistent** by moving it to class level and to create a little function you can call after such a change.

Here is an example of this functionality:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
        setCities(e.RowIndex, dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
}

void setCities(int row, string state)
{
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cityCell = 
                           (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[1]);
    cityCell.Items.Clear();
    cityCell.Items.AddRange(dict[state].ToArray());
    cityCell.Value = cityCell.Items[0];
}
```

Note that the new `cityCell.Value` shows up only after leaving the edited cell!

Final note: If you really want to display only one row per state, you need to change the loop that fills the `DGV` to loop not over your table but over the `dict.Keys` collection:

```
for (int i = 0; i <  dict.Keys.Count; i++)
{
    string state = dict.Keys.ElementAt(i);
    string city1 = dict[state][0].ToString();
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell stateCell = 
                            (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0]);
    stateCell.Items.AddRange(dict.Keys.ToArray());
    stateCell.Value = state;
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cityCell = 
                            (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1]);
    cityCell.Items.AddRange(dict[state].ToArray());
    cityCell.Value = city1;
}
```