# set value in combobox inside datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, combobox

I Have Datagridview with combobox inside and i can't set the index in code
I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778621/set-selected-items-for-datagridview-combobox-failed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5976511/how-to-set-value-to-datagridviewcombobox-column) - both not work.

here is my code:

```
  dgShuffle.DataSource = dtCards;
  DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
  cmb.HeaderText = "Select Data";
  cmb.Name = "cmb";
  cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 2;
  cmb.Items.Add("real");
  cmb.Items.Add("sham");

  dgShuffle.Columns.Add(cmb);
  for (int i = 0; i < dgShuffle.RowCount; i++)
  {
       (dgShuffle.Rows[i].Cells[6] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = "real";
        // dgShuffle.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = "real";
  }
```

To set by code i mean : programmatically (depend on the value in datatble).
I Dont Get error at all. the value simply not display in the combobox

I checked the index of the combobox and this is correct , below the output from my immediate window:

> ?dgShuffle.Rows[i].Cells[6]
>
> {DataGridViewComboBoxCell { ColumnIndex=6, RowIndex=0 }}    [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxCell]: {DataGridViewComboBoxCell { ColumnIndex=6, RowIndex=0 }}
>       base: {DataGridViewComboBoxCell { ColumnIndex=6, RowIndex=0 }}
>       AccessibilityObject: {System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCell.DataGridViewCellAccessibleObject}
>       ColumnIndex: 6
>       ContentBounds: {X = 0 Y = 12 Width = 0 Height = 0}
>       ContextMenuStrip: null
>       DefaultNewRowValue: null
>       Displayed: false
>       EditedFormattedValue: ""
>       EditType: {Name = "DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl" FullName = "System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewComboBoxEditingControl"}
>       ErrorIconBounds: {X = 0 Y = 0 Width = 0 Height = 0}
>       ErrorText: ""
>       FormattedValue: ""
>       FormattedValueType: {Name = "String" FullName = "System.String"}
>       Frozen: false
>       HasStyle: false
>       InheritedState: Resizable | ResizableSet | Visible
>       InheritedStyle: {DataGridViewCellStyle { BackColor=Color [Window], ForeColor=Color [ControlText], SelectionBackColor=Color [Highlight], SelectionForeColor=Color [HighlightText], Font=[Font: Name=Microsoft Sans Serif, Size=7.8, Units=3, GdiCharSet=177, GdiVerticalFont=False], WrapMode=False, Alignment=MiddleLeft }}
>       IsInEditMode: false
>       OwningColumn: {DataGridViewComboBoxColumn { Name=cmb, Index=6 }}
>       OwningRow: {DataGridViewRow { Index=0 }}
>       PreferredSize: {Width = 43 Height = 26}
>       ReadOnly: false
>       Resizable: true
>       RowIndex: 0
>       Selected: false
>       Size: {Width = 100 Height = 24}
>       Style: {DataGridViewCellStyle { }}
>       Tag: null
>       ToolTipText: ""
>       Value: null
>       ValueType: {Name = "Object" FullName = "System.Object"}
>       Visible: true

## Next try :

1. I create a new winforms project
2. Drag datagridview to the default form (from the toolbox)
3. Copy this code to  Form1_Load :

   ```
       DataTable dtCards;
       dtCards = new DataTable();
       dtCards.Columns.Add("printedString");
       dtCards.Rows.Add("1");
       dtCards.Rows.Add("2");
       dtCards.Rows.Add("3");
       dtCards.Rows.Add("4");
       dataGridView1.DataSource = dtCards;

       DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
       cmb.HeaderText = "Select Data";
       cmb.Name = "cmb";
       cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 2;
       cmb.Items.Add("real");
       cmb.Items.Add("sham");

       dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);
       for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.RowCount; i++)
       {
           (dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell).Value = "real";
           // dgShuffle.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = "real";
       }
   ```

What am i missing???

Comment: "i can't set the index in code" what do you mean ? what is your goal exactly ?

Comment: Wrap it in a `try/catch`, do you get an error? I don't understand the need to cast, the code `dgShuffle.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value = "real";` should work fine as long as that value is available in the drop-down.

Comment: Don't really understand your question. I have just tested your code block and it works fine. Did you set the wrong columns index ?

Comment: Your ComboBoxColumn show, you can change its value on run-time but can not programmatically ?
Ps: Still don't see anything wrong in your code. Could you provide other code that affect your DataGridView ? Maybe try deleting your DataGridView and create new one to avoid design-time errors ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using datagridview bounded to the data source. You need specify that value in the datasource.

Add value for `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` in the data source
Then set `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName` to the name of the column/property of your data source

```
DataTable dtCards;
dtCards = new DataTable();
dtCards.Columns.Add("printedString");
dtCards.Columns.Add("comboboxValue", typeof(String)); //adding column for combobox
dtCards.Rows.Add("1", "real");
dtCards.Rows.Add("2", "real");
dtCards.Rows.Add("3", "real");
dtCards.Rows.Add("4", "real");


DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cmb = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
cmb.HeaderText = "Select Data";
cmb.Name = "cmb";
cmb.MaxDropDownItems = 2;
cmb.Items.Add("real");
cmb.Items.Add("sham");
cmb.DataPropertyName = "comboboxValue"; //Bound value to the datasource

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(cmb);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dtCards;
```

Comment: But what if I want to filter the combobx based on the value I enter to combobox?

Comment: Is it possible to set difference combobox values for different rows from the same List?

Comment: @Dimi, datasource for combobox column shared between all rows. For getting different items for different rows - you should set own items collection for every combobox cell. Check this: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/27202221/1565525](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27202221/1565525)