# Filling on datagridviewcombobox according to database mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a datagridView which has 2 columns that will be filled by the database.
In the database I have this: 
Column1 : Name       Column2 : Quantity       Column 3 : Date

a                     1                       2019

b                     2                       2018

c                     3                       2017

a                     4                       2015

So what I need is to show in my combobox for Name a : (1 - 2019)(4 -  2015)
Here what I did :

```
using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT DISTINCT Name ,CONCAT(Quantite ,'PCS -' ,Date) as Conc FROM articles", MyConnexion))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            DTG_Bordereau.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
            DTG_Bordereau.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Name";

            DTG_Bordereau.Columns[3].Width = 300;

            DTG_Bordereau.DataSource = dt;

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                  {
                var val = dt.Rows[i]["Conc"].ToString();

                //check if it already exists
                if (!QuantiteDisponible.Items.Contains(val))
                {
                    QuantiteDisponible.Items.Add(val);
                }

            }
```

Comment: So, what happens? What is the question? There are many examples of doing it; you can even bind the Items..

Comment: the problem is that in the combobox all the items are filled not distinct one

Comment: What you make is double click on the datagridview, and in the new method ,yu get the name, clear the combobox and add only the val that has in the same row thename a

Comment: how ? I tried many times.....

Comment: what Did you try? if (dt.Rows[i][ "Name "].ToString() = "a")  { before your //check if it already exists and of course a } after the block

Comment: to get "a" i have to loop right ? the looping is not working for me...

Comment: _all the items are filled not distinct one_ meaning what?

Comment: all values from column 2 and 3 are filled in the combobox but I want only the value which corresponds to the column 1 like I explained

Comment: TaW :  I have the same problem like this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201551/datagridview-comboboxcolumn-different-values-for-each-row , how did you figure it out ?

Answer (score 0):

```
using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(@"SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM articles", MyConnexion))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            DTG_Bordereau.AutoResizeColumns(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.AllCells);
            DTG_Bordereau.Columns[0].DataPropertyName = "Name";



            DTG_Bordereau.Columns[3].Width = 300;
            DTG_Bordereau.DataSource = dt;





                try
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                    {


                        QuantiteDisponible.Items.Clear();

                    MySqlDataAdapter sda2 = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT CONCAT(Quantite ,'PCS -' ,Date) as Conc FROM articles where Name='" + dt.Rows[i][0].ToString() + "'", MyConnexion);
                    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();

                    sda2.Fill(dt2);
                    QuantiteDisponible.DataSource = dt2;

                    QuantiteDisponible.DisplayMember = "Conc";
                    QuantiteDisponible.ValueMember = "Conc";

                }


            }

                catch
                { }



        }
```

So with this code, my first combobox is correct, but the other comboboxes are taking the same value of the first combobox....